# Global style override for MUI Select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to style a `select` component in a react project using MUI 5, specifically, I'm trying to change the border size and color when the `select` component is focused. Other components can be globally styled just fine using styleOverrides followed by root but `select` doesn't seem to have the root attribute. Tried changing the `select` component into a `textfield` component with the select prop and that seemed to work but I was wondering if there's a way to style `select` without changing them into `textfield`.

This is the code snippet that I use for my `textfield` global style overrides:

```
export const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiTextField: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused fieldset': { border: '3px solid #A6CBF3'},
       },
     },
   },
})
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I could change the style for the focus state for the `Select` component using the theme.

```
export const theme = createTheme({
      components: {
        MuiSelect: {
          styleOverrides: {
            select: {
              ":focus": {
                backgroundColor: "green", // Just for the demo
                border: '3px solid #A6CBF3',
              },
            },
    
          }
        },
    })
```

Hope it helped, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't documented anywhere, but `'root'` appears to still work. Even though it's not available through the type system.

You could try:

```js
export const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiSelect: {
      styleOverrides: {
        ...{'root': {
          outline: '1px red solid'
        }}
      }
    }
  }
})
```